# Node.JS Process global event listeners

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, event-handling, eventemitter

I was wondering if there is any way i could declare event listeners on the Node.JS' `process` module. i.e being able to define event listeners in one file globally which applies to the entire project.

For example: I want to be able to listen to the process module's `on(exit)` event to perform some logging before the process quits with the mentioned or default `exitCode` (This is in a saperate file from where i'd call the `process.exit()`

```
if(!process.env.TELEGRAM_TOKEN) {
   process.exit(100);
}
```

and i have the listener in another module declared as:

```
process.on("exit", (code) => {
switch(code) {
    case 100:
        console.error(`${code} - ${NO_API_KEYS}`);
        break;
    default:
        console.error(`${code} - ${DEFAULT_EXIT_ERROR}`)
}
});
```

Problem is - It exits with code `100` but it never logs the `console.error()` defined on the event listener.

Comment: Well, `process` is a global object so you can listen to the `exit` or `message` or `beforeExit` messages or any of the other messages it emits from anywhere in your project.  For example, you can put this anywhere: `process.on('exit', function(existCode) { /* your code here */});`.

Comment: @jfriend00 i did try that, But it only listens when the process event is executed from the same file as the listener.

Comment: Yes, @p2pdops that's an option but i thought the process is supposed to be a global object and should be acting as a singleton if i'm not wrong?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "process event is executed from the same file"? You can listen to `process.on('exit', ...)` from ANY file in your nodejs process. If that's not working, then you are doing something wrong and need to show your code so we can help you see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @jfriend00 i've updated the post with my code, please check it out

Comment: There is no need to `import process`.  It is a global.  You can just directly reference it without importing.  I don't know if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: I just tried it without too, still the same

Comment: Are you 100% sure that other module is actually loaded and running?  If you put a `console.log("registering process.on(exit) handlers")` right before the `process.on('exit', ...)` code, does that show in the console?  I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Plus, if you look at the code ]here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/process/per_thread.js#L175) for `process.exit()`, you can see that it calls `process.emit('exit', process.exitCode)` which will synchronously call all registered handlers for the `exit` event.

Comment: Okay, i think that module is never being reached/loaded. How do I export it to run on application start? Any opinions? @jfriend00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your module is not being loaded so the code is never being run to register the event handlers for the `exit` event.

All you have to do to get its initialization code to run is to import the module from your main app module or any other module of yours that is part of your app initialization.

```
import './mymodule.js'
```